# change the config in angular2-query-builder dynamically

Tags: angular, html, css, typescript

Here, i am trying to change the operators based on the field value in Angular2-query-builder. My TS file.

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
        <div>
          <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
        </div>
        <query-builder [(ngModel)]='uiExpression' [config]='config' (ngModelChange)="apply()" #que (onChangeCallback)="onchange()">
              <ng-container *queryButtonGroup="let ruleset; let addRule=addRule; let addRuleSet=addRuleSet; let removeRuleSet=removeRuleSet">
                <button mat-button (click)="addRule()">+ Rule</button>
                <button mat-button (click)="addRuleSet()">+ Ruleset</button>
                <button mat-button (click)="removeRuleSet()">- Ruleset</button>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container *queryRemoveButton="let rule; let removeRule=removeRule">
                <button mat-icon-button color="accent" (click)="removeRule(rule)">
                  <mat-icon>remove</mat-icon>
                </button>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container *querySwitchGroup="let ruleset">
                <mat-radio-group *ngIf="ruleset" [(ngModel)]="ruleset.condition">
                  <mat-radio-button value="and">And</mat-radio-button>
                  <mat-radio-button value="or">Or</mat-radio-button>
                </mat-radio-group>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container *queryInput="let rule; type: 'string'">
                <mat-form-field>
                  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="rule.value">
                </mat-form-field>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container *queryInput="let rule; type: 'number'">
                <mat-form-field>
                  <input matInput type="number" [(ngModel)]="rule.value">
                </mat-form-field>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container *queryInput="let rule; type: 'date'">
                <mat-form-field>
                  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="rule.value">
                  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container *queryInput="let rule; let field=field; let options=options; type: 'multiselect'">
                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-select multiple [(ngModel)]="rule.value">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt.value">
                      {{ opt.name }}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container *queryField="let rule; let fields=fields; let changeField=changeField">
                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="rule.field" (ngModelChange)="changeFields($event, rule)">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let field of fields" [value]="field.value">{{field.name}}</mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container *queryOperator="let rule; let operators=operators">
                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="rule.operator" (ngModelChange)="changeOperator(rule)">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let value of operators" [value]="value">{{value}}</mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
              </ng-container>
              </query-builder>
            <div>{{userExpression}}</div>
      `,
    })    
    export class App {
public operators = [
        {
            "attributeType": "STRING",
            "operators": [
                { "displayOperator": "Equals", "sqlOperator": " =(VALUE)" },
                { "displayOperator": "Does not Equal", "sqlOperator": "<>(VALUE)" },
                { "displayOperator": "Starts With", "sqlOperator": "LIKE %(VALUE)" },
                { "displayOperator": "Ends With", "sqlOperator": "LIKE (VALUE)%" },
                { "displayOperator": "Contains", "sqlOperator": "LIKE %(VALUE)%" },
                { "displayOperator": "Does Not Contain", "sqlOperator": "NOT LIKE %(VALUE)" },
                { "displayOperator": "Does Not Start With", "sqlOperator": "NOT LIKE (VALUE)%" },
                { "displayOperator": "Does Not End With", "sqlOperator": "NOT LIKE %(VALUE)%" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "attributeType": "Numeric",
            "operators": [
                { "displayOperator": "Equals", "sqlOperator": " =(VALUE)" },
                { "displayOperator": "Does not Equal", "sqlOperator": "<>(VALUE)" },
                { "displayOperator": "Greater", "sqlOperator": ">(VALUE)" },
                { "displayOperator": "Equal or Greater", "sqlOperator": ">=(VALUE)" },
                { "displayOperator": "Less", "sqlOperator": "<(VALUE)" },
                { "displayOperator": "Equal or Less", "sqlOperator": "<=(VALUE)" },
                { "displayOperator": "Within", "sqlOperator": "BETWEEN (VALUE1) AND (VALUE2)" },
            ]
        },
        {
            "attributeType": "Date",
            "operators": [
                { "displayOperator": "Equals", "sqlOperator": " =(VALUE)" },
                { "displayOperator": "On or After", "sqlOperator": ">=(VALUE)" },
                { "displayOperator": "Before", "sqlOperator": "<(VALUE)" },
                { "displayOperator": "Between", "sqlOperator": "BETWEEN (VALUE1) AND (VALUE2)" }
            ]
        }
    ]
          AttributeDummy: any[] = [
            {
              "userColumnName": "Attribute 1",
              "colType": "multiselect",
              "isListType": "Y",
              "userColumnOptions": [
                { name: "Male", value: "m" },
                { name: "Female", value: "f" }
              ]
            },
            {
              "userColumnName": "Attribute 2",
              "colType": "date",
              "isListType": "N",
              "userColumnOptions": ""
            },
            {
              "userColumnName": "Attribute 3",
              "colType": "string",
              "isListType": "N",
              "userColumnOptions": ""
            },
            {
              "userColumnName": "Attribute 4",
              "colType": "number",
              "isListType": "N",
              "userColumnOptions": ""
            }
          ]
          name: string;
          uiExpression = {};
          fieldsS = {}
          @Input() config: QueryBuilderConfig = {
            fields: {}
          }
          userExpression: String = 'Attribute = undefined';
          constructor() {
            this.name = `Plunker! v${VERSION.full}`;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.AttributeDummy.length; i++) {
              // operators: (this.AttributeDummy[i].colType.toLowerCase()==this.operator.operators[0].attributeType.toLowerCase()) ? this.operator.operators[0].operators : 
              // (this.AttributeDummy[i].colType.toLowerCase()==this.operator.operators[1].attributeType.toLowerCase()) ? this.operator.operators[1].operators : 
              // (this.AttributeDummy[i].colType.toLowerCase()==this.operator.operators[2].attributeType.toLowerCase()) ? this.operator.operators[2].operators : ''
              this.fieldsS[this.AttributeDummy[i].userColumnName] = {
                name: this.AttributeDummy[i].userColumnName,
                type: this.AttributeDummy[i].colType.toLowerCase(),
                operators: this.operators,
                options: this.AttributeDummy[i].userColumnOptions
              }
              this.config.fields = this.fieldsS;
              this.detect.markForCheck();
              console.log('config ', JSON.stringify(this.config))
            }
            if (this.AttributeDummy.length > 0) {
              console.log('attributes length > 0');
              this.uiExpression = {
                condition: 'and',
                rules: [
                  {
                    field: this.AttributeDummy[0].userColumnName,
                    operator: this.operators[0]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

while changing the attribute am trying to update operators in the query builder dynamically into the UI. I updating the operators list into config but it won't updating into the UI.

Here, one reference link: https://zebzhao.github.io/Angular-QueryBuilder/demo/ I want to update the operators based on the field.

Comment: Can you please post also the value of the [(ngModel)] and [config]? At least, 1 sample field

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find any good documentation for this. I was able to get it working though by reading through the query-builder.component.js src to see how it works.

I'm using

- angular2-query-builder 0.4.2
- angular 8.0.0

Add a reference to your QueryBuilderComponent.

```
  @ViewChild(QueryBuilderComponent, { static: true }) queryBuilder: QueryBuilderComponent;
```

then after you update your config, call changeField on the queryBuilder to update the UI with the new config values.

```
//set the options for your field
this.config.fields['myField'].options = [
   {name: 'a', value:'1'}, 
   {name: 'b', value:'2'}, 
   {name: 'c', value:'3'}
]

this.refreshField('myField);



private refreshField(field: string): void {
    // get the current rule
    const srcRule = this.queryBuilder.data.rules.find((x: Rule) => x.field === field) as Rule;

    if (srcRule) {

      // cache the current rule's selected value from our datasource
      const value = srcRule ? srcRule.value : undefined;

      // call change field to rebind new options to the UI
      this.queryBuilder.changeField(field, srcRule);

      // reset the previously selected value to the dropdown because changeField nulls out the value.
      srcRule.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: We should set static to false inside ViewChild, because if we set it to true the queryBuilder variable is set before the change detection is run, and we would gte queryBuilder as undefined. After setting to false am able to access queryBuilder variable. Thanks for this solution.